# Make Firefox Panel fit content

Tags: firefox-addon-sdk

I'm manually porting an extension I wrote in Chrome over to Firefox. I'm attaching a panel to a widget, and setting the content of that panel as an HTML file. How can I make the panel shrink and grow with the content? There's a lot of unsightly scroll bars and grey background right now.

```
var data = require("self").data;

var text_entry = require("panel").Panel({
  width: 320,
  height: 181,
  contentURL: data.url("text-entry.html"),
  contentScriptFile: data.url("get-text.js")
});

require("widget").Widget({
  label: "Text entry",
  id: "text-entry",
  contentURL: "http://www.mozilla.org/favicon.ico",
  panel: text_entry
});
```

Not setting the height property of the panel makes it quite tall.

Comment: You can set height and widget in the panel on creation, obviously. Do you need these values to change dynamically as the panel content changes?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm looking for

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out this example that resizes the panel based on the document loaded. If you want to resize based on changes to the content size, at least on initial load:

https://builder.addons.mozilla.org/package/150225/latest/

( sorry for the delay in respinding, been afk travelling )

Comment: Did you mean to post a link?